# If and Contains Statement combined

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dimension that logs successes or failures. And I want to create a measure of each (Success and Failure Counts) from this string. I tried creating a calculated field but not sure what is going on: `(IF CONTAINS ([RESULT], "success") THEN "Success" ELSE "" END)`. Here is sample data:

```
Failure-2DispIn90Or0-Transfer   206
Failure-AcctOverDue-Transfer    625
Success-AppointConfirmMenu  738
Success-ApptFoundReview 1384
Success-Balance Playback    330
Success-BalanceDown 352
Success-FAQ Copy Playback   164
Success-FileAClaimMenu  570
Success-General FAQ Playback    388
Success-GetDispatchByContract Module    15247
Success-Move to Balance Menu    1830
Failure-ValidateContractEntry-Balance-Transfer  162
Failure-ValidateContractEntry-Claims Status-Hang Up 73
Failure-ValidateContractEntry-Claims Status-Normal  22
Failure-ValidateContractEntry-Claims Status-Transfer    170
Failure-ValidateContractEntry-Contract Status-Transfer  131
Failure-ValidateContractEntry-Schedule a Repair-Hang Up 441
Failure-ValidateContractEntry-Schedule a Repair-Transfer    1236
Failure-ValidatePhone Entry-Balance-Hang Up 208
```

Comment: Please ask a detailed question, now it's not clear what exactly you are asking. Show what did you already try and why do you think it's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You could go for something like:

Success/Failure:

```
IF STARTSWITH([Result],"Successs") = true THEN
    "Success"
ELSEIF STARTSWITH([Result],"Failure") = true THEN
    "Failure"
ELSE
    Null 
END
```

Colour the marks by the new calculated field.